# JavaCV Stream-Test code giving Error

Tags: android, ffmpeg, javacv

I'm hoping someone might be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong here. I downloaded vanevery's GitHub project “JavaCV-0.5-Stream-Test" which is a couple of years old so I updated to the latest JavaCV version 0.11. But Android Studio is returning the error...

**Error:**

> "record(org.bytedeco.javacpp.Frame) in FFmpegFrameRecorder cannot be
>   applied to (org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.lplimage)" for the line
>   of code which reads recorder.record(yuvIplimage), under
>   onPreviewFrame.

Here is my **code:**

```
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        if (yuvIplimage != null && recording) {

            videoTimestamp = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);

            // Put the camera preview frame right into the yuvIplimage object
            yuvIplimage.getByteBuffer().put(data);

            try {
                // Get the correct time
                recorder.setTimestamp(videoTimestamp);

                // Record the image into FFmpegFrameRecorder
                recorder.record(yuvIplimage);

            } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```